# Move all li items in a ul to a separate ul

Tags: javascript

Trying to move all list items in .origin ul to .target ul with vanilla javascript.

```
<div id="container">
  <span>Origin</span>
  <ul class="origin">
    <li class="level-top li-item">Origin entry 1</li>
    <li class="level-top li-item">Origin entry 2</li>
    <li class="level-top li-item">Origin entry 3</li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <span>Target</span>
  <ul class="target">
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
var origin = document.querySelector('.origin');
document.querySelector(".target").append(origin);
```

This moves them however, it puts the entire origin ul into the target ul.  Should I be iterating through the list items?

Comment: [There’s work to be done, whether it is homework or an assigned task , the person to whom it was assigned is expected to complete it. Even if it seems the task is too hard or there isn’t a clear starting point, an effort should be made.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append origin's children to target, like this:

```
const origin = document.querySelector('.origin');
const target = document.querySelector('.target');
target.append(...origin.childNodes);
```

or you can do it in one line like this:

```
document.querySelector('.target').append(...document.querySelector('.origin').childNodes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shornt and simple solution would be

```
const t = document.querySelector(".target")
t.innerHTML += o.innerHTML
o.innerHTML = ""
```